# Integrating cloudify with openstack nova-network

Tags: cloudify

Integrating cloudify with openstack nova-network, if nova-network dosn't support floating-ip, how to define the openstack-nova-net-manager-blueprint.yaml?

1.cloudify-manager-blueprints version: cloudify-manager-blueprints-3.2.1
https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-manager-blueprints/tree/3.2.1-build

2.the blueprint DSL like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n8jo.png)

how to solve this problem? thanks for your kindly help!

Answer (score 1):

The floating IP is used to connect to the manager once it has been already bootstrapped.

In case you do not have a floating IP, you can bypass it with one of two options:

1. Create manually an IP connected to the external network and use it as an external resource, so you it would look like:

   ```
   manager_server_ip:
     type: string
     default: 1.1.1.1

   manager_server:
       type: cloudify.openstack.nodes.Server
       properties:
         resource_id: { get_input: manager_server_name }
         manager_server_ip: { get_input: manager_server_ip }
         install_agent: false
         server:
           image: { get_input: image_id }
           flavor: { get_input: flavor_id }
         openstack_config: { get_property: [openstack_configuration,  openstack_config] }
       relationships:
         - target: management_security_group
           type: cloudify.openstack.server_connected_to_security_group
         - target: management_keypair
           type: cloudify.openstack.server_connected_to_keypair
   ```
2. Just create a regular IP on the some network that will let you connect the manager after bootstrap